# Java encryption performance to hide primary keys

Tags: java, security, google-app-engine, encryption

I need to hide certain raw values from end user output (mostly primary keys, could be ~100 of them per request) simply so that the database can't easily be probed or  iterated through. Speed of the encryption is of higher importance than the actual impenetrability of the values.

I am currently using `PBEWithMD5AndDES` in the following wrapper - is this overkill? I am new to using Java as a web backend.

```
public class SecurityHelper {
    private static final String DEFAULT_KEY = "some-key-here";
    private SecretKey secretKey;
    private PBEParameterSpec parameterSpec;
    private Cipher cipher;

    public SecurityHelper() {
        try {
            char[] moduleKeyChars = DEFAULT_KEY.toCharArray();
            KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(moduleKeyChars);
            secretKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(
              "PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);
            parameterSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(new byte[8], 1);
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String encrypt(String secret) {
        String encrypted = null;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, parameterSpec);
            byte[] stateBytes = cipher.doFinal(secret.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            encrypted = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(stateBytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encrypted;
    }

    public String decrypt(String encrypted) {
        String decrypted = null;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, parameterSpec);
            byte[] stringBinary = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(encrypted);
            decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(stringBinary));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return decrypted;
    }

}
```

Or am I dramatically better off using something like [XOR cipher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641563/xor-cipher-in-java-php-different-results)?

Comment: If you don't want to display primary keys, why _select them to be returned_ in the first place? This looks to me as a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Building an app API. The client will need the ids for other methods. Example: /fetch returns a bunch of ids, /delete requires one id.

Comment: Have you considered using/implementing an _authorization_ mechanism to prevent unauthorized access to your resources?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do want to hide the values from a user, I don't see why you should be either encrypting or hashing them. What you should be doing is to generate random and unique keys. Have you thought of using GUIDs instead ?

If you think GUIDs are too long, you could generate a random string of a predefined length. Make your database column a unique index for the benefit of faster searching.

This is how URL shortners such as bit.ly or goo.gl works. This would prevent anyone from crawling through your database using primary keys.

Comment: @Cal If **performance** is your main concern, consider _this answer_, since a GUID is only generated once and you completely eliminate any encryption/decryption or hashing/lookup on every request

Comment: This answer wont work. He cant make up the ids because he needs to map them back to the real id ehrn the user passes them back.

Comment: The GUIDs would be the "real ID", no mapping involved; OPs stated objective was to prevent probing for unauthorized resources

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *encryption* is probably overkill. You should however not fall into a trap and use less secure cryptographic primitives because of it. Especially using CBC mode security, a static salt etc. are really mistakes you should avoid. XOR or DES encryption is really not worth the name, these encryption schemes can be broken in minutes.

If encryption is overkill with regards to server performance is a question only you can answer. Usually IO and complex SQL queries will task your system more than simple symmetric encryption of a few bytes of data.

I'll show you your class retrofitted with GCM and - in case that's not available or if the tag size of 12 bytes is too much overhead - CTR mode encryption.

You should probably only do this if it is not possible to use (random) GUID's instead.

WARNING: I would not consider the following classes to have enough input parameter checking (integer overflows etc.). I get bored when trying to implement all those checks and JUnit tests (without getting payed for it anyway :P ). Sanitize your input before calling any of the functions.

AES/GCM:

```
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;

import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class SecurityHelperGCM {
    private static final int NONCE_SIZE = 8;
    private static final int TAG_SIZE = 12;
    // make sure that the hexadecimals represent a *truly random* byte array
    // (e.g. use SecureRandom)
    private final SecretKey STATIC_SECRET_KEY = new SecretKeySpec(
            hexDecode("66e517bb5fd7df840060aed7e8b58986"), "AES");
    private Cipher cipher;

    private static byte[] hexDecode(final String hex) {
        final byte[] data = new byte[hex.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 2),
                    16);
        }
        return data;
    }

    public SecurityHelperGCM() {
        try {
            this.cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static int generateRandomNonce(final byte[] nonceBuffer,
            final int offset, final int size) {
        final SecureRandom rng = new SecureRandom();
        final byte[] nonce = new byte[size];
        rng.nextBytes(nonce);
        System.arraycopy(nonce, 0, nonceBuffer, offset, size);
        clearArray(nonce);

        return offset + size;
    }

    private static void clearArray(final byte[] nonce) {
        // clean up...
        for (int i = 0; i < nonce.length; i++) {
            nonce[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    private static GCMParameterSpec generateGCMParametersFromNonce(
            final byte[] nonceBuffer, final int offset, final int size,
            final int blockSize) {
        final GCMParameterSpec gcmParameters = new GCMParameterSpec(TAG_SIZE
                * Byte.SIZE, nonceBuffer, offset, size);
        return gcmParameters;
    }

    public String encrypt(final String secret) {
        final byte[] plaintext = secret.getBytes(UTF_8);
        final byte[] nonceAndCiphertext = new byte[NONCE_SIZE
                + plaintext.length + TAG_SIZE];

        int offset = generateRandomNonce(nonceAndCiphertext, 0, NONCE_SIZE);
        final GCMParameterSpec nonceIV = generateGCMParametersFromNonce(
                nonceAndCiphertext, 0, NONCE_SIZE, this.cipher.getBlockSize());

        try {
            this.cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, this.STATIC_SECRET_KEY,
                    nonceIV);
            offset += this.cipher.doFinal(plaintext, 0, plaintext.length,
                    nonceAndCiphertext, offset);
            if (offset != nonceAndCiphertext.length) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "Something wrong during encryption");
            }
            // Java 8 contains java.util.Base64
            return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(nonceAndCiphertext);
        } catch (final GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Missing basic functionality from Java runtime", e);
        }
    }

    public String decrypt(final String encrypted) throws BadPaddingException {
        final byte[] nonceAndCiphertext = DatatypeConverter
                .parseBase64Binary(encrypted);
        final GCMParameterSpec nonceIV = generateGCMParametersFromNonce(
                nonceAndCiphertext, 0, NONCE_SIZE, this.cipher.getBlockSize());
        try {
            this.cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, this.STATIC_SECRET_KEY,
                    nonceIV);
            final byte[] plaintext = this.cipher.doFinal(nonceAndCiphertext,
                    NONCE_SIZE, nonceAndCiphertext.length - NONCE_SIZE);
            return new String(plaintext, UTF_8);
        } catch (final BadPaddingException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (final GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Missing basic functionality from Java runtime", e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final String secret = "owlstead";
        final SecurityHelperGCM securityHelperGCM = new SecurityHelperGCM();
        final String ct = securityHelperGCM.encrypt(secret);
        String pt = null;
        try {
            pt = securityHelperGCM.decrypt(ct);
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            System.out.println("Ciphertext tampered, take action!");
        }
        System.out.println(pt);
    }
}
```

AES/CTR:

```
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;

import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class SecurityHelperCTR {
    private static final int NONCE_SIZE = 8;
    // make sure that the hexadecimals represent a *truly random* byte array
    // (e.g. use SecureRandom)
    private final SecretKey STATIC_SECRET_KEY = new SecretKeySpec(
            hexDecode("66e517bb5fd7df840060aed7e8b58986"), "AES");
    private Cipher cipher;

    private static byte[] hexDecode(final String hex) {
        final byte[] data = new byte[hex.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 2),
                    16);
        }
        return data;
    }

    public SecurityHelperCTR() {
        try {
            this.cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static int generateRandomNonce(final byte[] nonceBuffer,
            final int offset, final int size) {
        final SecureRandom rng = new SecureRandom();
        final byte[] nonce = new byte[size];
        rng.nextBytes(nonce);
        System.arraycopy(nonce, 0, nonceBuffer, offset, size);
        return offset + size;
    }

    private static IvParameterSpec generateIVFromNonce(
            final byte[] nonceBuffer, final int offset, final int size,
            final int blockSize) {
        final byte[] ivData = new byte[blockSize];
        System.arraycopy(nonceBuffer, offset, ivData, 0, size);
        final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivData);
        return iv;
    }

    public String encrypt(final String secret) {
        final byte[] plaintext = secret.getBytes(UTF_8);
        final byte[] nonceAndCiphertext = new byte[NONCE_SIZE
                + plaintext.length];

        int offset = generateRandomNonce(nonceAndCiphertext, 0, NONCE_SIZE);
        final IvParameterSpec nonceIV = generateIVFromNonce(nonceAndCiphertext,
                0, NONCE_SIZE, this.cipher.getBlockSize());

        try {
            this.cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, this.STATIC_SECRET_KEY,
                    nonceIV);
            offset += this.cipher.doFinal(plaintext, 0, plaintext.length,
                    nonceAndCiphertext, offset);
            if (offset != nonceAndCiphertext.length) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "Something wrong during encryption");
            }
            // Java 8 contains java.util.Base64
            return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(nonceAndCiphertext);
        } catch (final GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Missing basic functionality from Java runtime", e);
        }
    }

    public String decrypt(final String encrypted) {
        final byte[] nonceAndCiphertext = DatatypeConverter
                .parseBase64Binary(encrypted);
        final IvParameterSpec nonceIV = generateIVFromNonce(nonceAndCiphertext,
                0, NONCE_SIZE, this.cipher.getBlockSize());
        try {
            this.cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, this.STATIC_SECRET_KEY,
                    nonceIV);
            final byte[] plaintext = this.cipher.doFinal(nonceAndCiphertext,
                    NONCE_SIZE, nonceAndCiphertext.length - NONCE_SIZE);
            // note: this may return an invalid result if the value is tampered
            // with
            // it may even contain more or less characters
            return new String(plaintext, UTF_8);
        } catch (final GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Missing basic functionality from Java runtime", e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final String secret = "owlstead";
        final SecurityHelperCTR securityHelper = new SecurityHelperCTR();
        final String ct = securityHelper.encrypt(secret);
        final String pt = securityHelper.decrypt(ct);
        System.out.println(pt);
    }
}
```